# PHP loop through all occurances of a substring in a string

Tags: php, html

Hello I have the following code:

```
 $StyleOcc1 = substr_count(strtolower($text), strtolower("style=&quot;"));  
   if($StyleOcc1 < '1'){
      $text = $text;
   }else{
      while($StyleOcc1 > '0'){
       preg_match('~style=&quot;(.*?)&quot;>~', $text, $output);

       $outputD = $output[1];

       if($outputD != null){       
        $outputD = str_replace("&quot;","",$outputD);
        $outputD = str_replace(" ","",$outputD);
       }
       $text = str_replace($out[1], "", $text);
       $text = str_replace("style=&quot;".$output[1]."&quot;","style=&quot;".$outputD."&quot;",$text);
       $StyleOcc1 -=1;
      }
   }
```

The code is supposed to find `style=&quot;` in a body of text and replace it with `style=&quot;+more stuff that is not relevant to the question`. The problem is it does the first one perfectly but because I add `style=&quot;` in, it just keeps doing the first one repeatedly. How can I make it move on to the next one when the first one is done? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Basically what I want is the following. I have five occurences of the same substring in a string and I want to replace the first one with the letter a and the second occurence with the letter b and so on. How do i do this?

Comment: If you just want to add stuff to every `style=&quot;`, why not just use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) (it actually replaces all occurences) alone? (eg. `$str = str_replace('style=&quot;', 'style=&quot;+more stuff blabla', $str);`)

Comment: Basically what I want to do is find all occureneces of a string and replace the first one with (exmaple) 'a' the second occurence with 'b', the third with 'c' and so on for all occurences.